# Two's Complement Value of 011101

Tags: binary, twos-complement

I know the answer is 29 but I'm not sure how to arrive at it.

Usually I would take 011101 get its inverse of 100010 and add 1 to get
100011.

The value of this is 35. How then is the answer 29?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
011101 is 29  //Binary to Decimal
100011 + 011101 = 000000  //100011 is inverse+1
100011 = -011101  
100011 = -29
```

There is no '35' because in a two's compliment system any number starting with a '1' is a negative number.  This means, assuming 6 bits, that any number greater than 31 (011111) is in fact a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

The term "two's complement" is [ambiguous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Potential_ambiguities_of_terminology).

- `011101` is the two's complement *representation* of the decimal number 29.
- Performing the two's complement *operation* on `011101` results in `100011` (decimal -29, since two's complement notation uses the most-significant-bit as the sign bit).

Answer (score 0):

100011 is correct, and its decimal equivalent is indeed 35.  How do you know it should be 29?

Answer (score 0):

The answer *is* 35, not 29.

```
invert(0b011101) + 0b1 = 0b100010 + 0b1 = 0b100011 = 35
```

The *question* was for the two's complement of 29:

```
0b011101 = 29
```

Answer (score 0):

The "inverse +1" procedure is for encoding negative numbers.

You know this number is positive because the high bit is zero, so:

`1*2^4 + 1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 = 16 + 8 + 4 + 0 + 1 = 29`